# Postgres returning timing of query within actual query?

Tags: postgresql, timing

Is it possible to return the time taken for a query in postgres?

Normally you would use `\timing` in psql, but is it possible to get this value from a query alone, i.e. that I would use in a prepared statement?

Comment: `explain (analyze)` can show you that. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54387246/create-a-function-to-check-execution-time-using-explain-analyze-in-postgres) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694581)